# CrudRepository: saveAll - No property saveAll found for type

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Trying to create a saveAll method for an Iterable of entites.

Full error is Failed to create query method public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.myCompany.mappingPoc.ConnectionManagerRepo.saveAll(java.lang.Iterable)! No property saveAll found for type ConnectionManager!

```
@Repository
public interface ConnectionManagerRepo extends CrudRepository<ConnectionManager, Long> {

Iterable<ConnectionManager> findAllByControlId(Long controlId);

Page<ConnectionManager> findAllByControlId(Pageable p, Long controlId);

Iterable<ConnectionManager> saveAll(Iterable<ConnectionManager> connectionManagers);
}
```

Comment: CrudRepository already has a <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

Answer (score 5):

As *C. Weber* writes in his comment

> CrudRepository already has a `<S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);`

You don't need to specify your own.

You seem to expect some kind of query derivation happening here, but that mechanism only works for methods starting with `find`, `exists`, `count` and `delete`.